# A few questions relating to counting for midterm practise exam?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

I'm doing some questions for my midterm practise exam (multiple choice) for discrete structures and would appreciate some help (My answer is bolded):

Using the 26-letter alphabet {a,b,c,...,z}, how many different 20-letter strings are there that start with abxy, end with pq, and contain exactly 4 k’s?

A) $\binom{14}{4}$4!$10^{25}$

B) $\binom{14}{4}$$10^{25}$

**C) $\binom{14}{10}$$25^{10}$**

D) None of the above

I think it will be C since 6 have a set position, thus 14 and then the 10 is from 4 being k's, thus knowing their value.

-

What is the coefficient of $x^{12}y^{15}$ in the expansion of $(−3x + 7y)^{27}$?

A) $\binom{27}{12}$

**B) -$\binom{27}{15} 3^{12} 7^{15}$**

C) $\binom{27}{15} 7^{12} 3^{15}$

D) $\binom{27}{15} 3^{12} 7^{15}$

This was a guess just based on the numbers and the negative.

-

Let A be a set of size 6 and let B be a set of size 5. How many different functions are there from A to B that are not one-to-one?

A) $6^5$

**B) $5^6$ - 5!**

C) $5^6$

D) $6^5$ - $\binom{6}{5}$

I think it's b because the total number of mappings is $5^6$ while 5! removes all the none one-to-one thus receiving the desired answer

-

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is fine.

For the second you want to look at the binomial theorem:

$$(-3x+7y)^{27}=\sum_{k=0}^{27}\binom{27}k(-3x)^k(7y)^{27-k}\;.$$

Clearly you want the term in which $k=12$, which is $$\binom{27}{12}(-3x)^{12}(7y)^{15}=3^{12}7^{15}\binom{27}{12}x^{12}y^{15}\;,$$ so the correct answer is D. The even power on $x$ kills the minus sign.

For the third one, note that no function from $A$ to $B$ can be one-to-one: there aren’t enough elements in $B$. (This is really just an application of the pigeonhole principle.) Since (as you said) there are $5^6$ functions altogether, the correct answer is C.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you mind explaining the one-to-one a bit more? Maybe another example if you don't mind? I'm a bit confused still. Thanks again.

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy: No matter what the sets $A$ and $B$ are, if $|A|>|B|$, there can be no one-to-one function from $A$ to $B$. Suppose that $A=n$, $|B|=m$, $m>n$, and $f:A\to B$. For each $b\in B$ let $A_b=\{a\in A:f(a)=b\}$. The sets $A_b$ are pairwise disjoint, since $f$ cannot send any element of $A$ to two different elements of $B$, so every element of $A$ is in exactly one $A_b$. The sets $A_b$ are the pigeonholes, and you’re stuffing the elements of $A$ into them. There are $n$ elements of $A$ and only $m$ pigeonholes, so some $A_b$ has to contain at least two different ...

Comment: ... members of $A$, say $a_1$ and $a_2$. But that means that $f(a_1)=b=f(a_2)$ and hence that $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now!

Comment: @StackPWRequirmentsAreCrazy: You’re welcome!